# Internet IPv6 address shows up instead of normal IP in Gmail activity information page, may have been hacked, how to solve the issue?

Tags: ip, gmail

I am currently having an issue with Gmail through Activity information page where a new page pops up and the IP shows IPV6 address instead of normal IP address like 16.22.124.22 and I think I may have been hacked as I have already been hacked before. Moreover the IP address it used to show around 3 weeks back was normal IP address and was of the ISP location and not the city where I am based.

I cannot give a print shot of the Gmail Details page, but under activity information it something looks like

India (MH) (2406:e00:110:d7ac:c0b:2df2:2614:j167)

MH above is Maharashtra, the ISP location and not my location in another state. Internet IPv6 changes every time I log off and on the system and connect the internet again.

I currently use these things from India.

- I use a laptop with broadband modem.
- No antivirus
- No VPN
- Windows 7 Ultimate old version
- Old Chrome installed nearly 3 years back, not updated(because I have lost all my bookmarks before due to installation of new chrome so I did not instal new chrome afterwards)
- Two factor authentication on Gmail is on and works normal.

I am not a computer geek who can fix virus, hacking attempts etc. I am surprised I used to have normal ip address like 15.22.230.22 before but I am getting IPv6 address, have already been hacked before and this time again a new story. Help!

Comment: What is a “normal” IP address for you and why wouldn’t an IPv6 address be a “normal” one? If your ISP recently started providing you with IPv6 (good thing IMHO), then it is normal that you connect to gmail through IPv6 and that your IPv6 address shows up in gmail.

Comment: IPv6 source addresses are also very common when connecting from a mobile device. If you don't allow or expect, IPv6 addresses to connect to you maybe you should disable IPv6 on your system. How is your IPv6 firewalling currently configured? Sometimes people will have a well-configured IPv4 firewall and leave IPv6 wide-open. Ultimately, I think IPv6 is a good thing and it should be allowed but if you aren't ready for that yet maybe turn it off until you are.

Comment: Please do keep your browser and OS up to date! Using outdated browser is a very high security risk. The best way to ease migration pain is to update more often, not less. The migration code from supported versions are generally much better tested than from long out of date versions.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this was your real ipv6 address. If the ip came with `*` at the end, it could be 99.99% your ipv6.

Also don't get the information about the IP by google 100% correct, NO! As I get a vary location since my ip is valid every week.

You simply change your password with a strong string, plus enable two-authentication and in the activity window ask google to log out all other sessions just your current one.